# How to share environment properties between apps in manifest in PCF

Tags: manifest, pcf

I have a single manfiest to deploy a set of services. Some of these services use same environment variables. Is there a way I can group common configuration across apps in manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try this:

1. create a file called env-mainfest.yml with content:
   `---`
   `env`
    `name: value`

and use below in your manifest files for deployment

```
inherit: env-mainfest.yml
```

2. Isn't a good idea to have `spring_active_profiles` set with `env:` specific settings for all services and just create an application-system.properties file and use spring profiles OR something similar if not spring based?

Answer (score 0):

1. create base manifest file with common env variables for all services.
2. Create service specific manifest file like, manifest-.yml
3. Inherit base yml file in service specific manifest file.
   Start application specific file with inheriting base yml file

> ```
> ---
> inherit: manifest.yml
> <application specific env properties>
> ```